# Sum Column A While Not Summing Column B Depending On Column C - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to devise a method of always summing column A (Units) and sometimes summing column B (Price) depending on the value of column C (Version) while rolling up to the column D (Product) level. I am thinking of using a case when statement, but the issue I am running into revolves around the dependence on Price which has kind of a tiered system.  I have to take the Price value of the Current Version where available, then the Price value of the Recent Version where available, then if both Current and Recent Versions are not available, I need to take the Price value of the Old Version. The tier list goes Current > Recent > Old. Right now the data is in SQL Server.

To add another wrinkle, if the same Product has different Prices for two higher Version tiers, the returned Price should be different than the Price of the oldest Version. For example, if three rows for the same Product had Prices of 50, 50, and 10 and Versions of Old, Recent, and Recent (respectively), the returned Price would be 10.

So if the starting data looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  Units      |  Price  |  Version    | Product  |
--------------------------------------------------
|  105        |  50     |  Old        | Bear     |
--------------------------------------------------
|  100        |  100    |  Recent     | Bear     |
--------------------------------------------------
|  100        |  150    |  Current    | Bear     |
--------------------------------------------------
|  97         |  50     |  Old        | Bear     |
--------------------------------------------------
|  67         |  50     |  Old        | Goose    |
--------------------------------------------------
|  28         |  50     |  Recent     | Goose    |
--------------------------------------------------
|  10         |  10     |  Recent     | Goose    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The rolled up version of the data will look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  Units      |  Price  |  Version    | Product  |
--------------------------------------------------
|  402        |  150    |  Current    | Bear     |
--------------------------------------------------
|  105        |  10     |  Recent     | Goose    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I am new to SQL so apologies if this is a rookie question. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is using the WITH TIES clause in concert with Row_Number()

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties 
       Units = sum(Units) over (Partition By Product)
      ,Price
      ,Version
      ,Product
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Product Order by case when Version='Old' then 3 when Version='Recent' then 2 else 1 end)
```

**Returns**

```
Units   Price   Version   Product
402     150     Current   Bear
95      10      Recent    Goose
```

> **EDIT - Requested Update**

Here, we use the lag() function within a CTE to determine the change in price

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Units] int,[Price] int,[Version] varchar(50),[Product] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (105,50,'Old','Bear')
,(100,100,'Recent','Bear')
,(100,150,'Current','Bear')
,(97,50,'Old','Bear')
,(67,50,'Old','Goose')
,(28,50,'Recent','Goose')
,(10,10,'Recent','Goose')

;with cte as (
Select Units = sum(Units) over (Partition By Product)
      ,Price
      ,Version
      ,Product
      ,PrevPrice = abs(Price-lag(Price,1) over (Partition By Product Order by case when Version='Old' then 3 when Version='Recent' then 2 else 1 end desc) )
 From  @YourTable
)
Select top 1 with ties
       Units 
      ,Price
      ,Version
      ,Product
 From  cte
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Product Order by case when Version='Old' then 3 when Version='Recent' then 2 else 1 end ,PrevPrice desc)
```

**Returns**

```
Units   Price   Version Product
402     150     Current Bear
105     10      Recent  Goose
```

Comment: Thanks John, this is very helpful. I have the same question for you as I had for Gordon: I found a complication in my actual data where there are two distinct Price values that are both "Current" and I need to choose the value that is different from the "Recent" Price value. How could I modify the code to handle that situation?

Comment: @user3347996 Perhaps if you update your question with a new sample data and desired results.  I'm sure lag() would be able to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks John. I updated the question with new sample data and changed the desired results per your suggestion.

Comment: @user3347996 See EDIT

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  The trick is to order by your priority.  One method uses `row_number()` and `case`:

```
select sum(units) as units,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as price,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then version end) as version,
       product
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product
                                order by (case version when 'old' then 3 when 'recent' then 2 when 'current' then 1 else 4 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by product;
```

Comment: Great answer, this perfectly solves my example data. I found a complication in my actual data where there are two distinct Price values that are both "Current" and I need to choose the value that is different from the "Recent" Price value. How could I modify the code to handle that situation?